# Can I use bar tape on my (non race bike) bike with flat handles (not drop bars)

Tags: handlebars, handlebar-tape

My handle bars are slippery so during the drive they often start sliding off. Could I use those nice cool tapes on my handle bar? If so, which ones should I buy?

Comment: You also have a choice of grips that lock on to the bars.

Answer (score 4):

You can use any road tape on a flat bar. The main reason people do it is to make the grips thin and firm. Even a thick tape will be thinner than a thin grip. It's important to choose a wrap orientation where the torque from your hand is working the tape in the tightening direction. For a typical flat bar that means turn the tape clockwise looking at the bike from the right or counterclockwise from the left. Usually it works better to locate the finishing tape on the end of the bar as opposed to the brake lever because you want to avoid twisting on it directly, but that part depends on where you prefer to put your hands on the bar.

Finding the wrap orientation that resists loosening for you depends on habits and weight distribution and can tend to require some experimentation, but most riders find there to be one that works best.

Comment: I'll mention that "hockey tape" is a quick, cheap, and simple stand-in for regular bar tape.  A lot easier to install and it's less likely to shift over time.  The stuff's available (in many colors) from most sporting goods shops (at least those in the northern tier of the US).

Comment: so is the tightening direction the one that is forward going (away from your body) or backwards (as if you are giving more throttle on a motorbike)? :)

Comment: Away from your body.

Comment: Interesting - could be a new question.  I found that bartape on flat bars works great, but it would work loose when wrapped from rear, forwards over the top, and down.  The hand's clenching movement seems to work better when the bartape goes from front to back over the top, for me.  Didn't make a difference if it was wrapped from stem to ends or the other way.

Comment: I also cheated and used the brake or shifter to clamp the very end of the thin bartape rather than having tape right under the hand there.

Comment: @Criggie Yeah, to be honest I think there are forces happening in both directions and neither is perfect. My suspicion is that most of the time, static weight from the rider is pulling the tape in a way that adds tension back to front, but I could also see habit or position playing a role, like maybe some riders push straight down or otherwise apply negligible twisting forces most of the time but twist back when climbing or something. I associate taped flat bars with XC racers and they have pretty bent-over positions, so that may cloud my thinking. I amended my response.

Comment: I'm with @Criggie 's train of thought, wrapping the tape over the top backwards towards the seated rider. Furthermore I'd  start wrapping from the middle towards the ends of the bar, remove the standard grips and cleanly tuck the end of the tape into the bar. Then hold it in place with the plugs. If thicker bar-ends are required an extra layer of old style cloth tape underneath would do.

Comment: And if you wrap the bartape in a way that doesn't work for you, it is easy enough to unwrap most bartapes and do it over.

Comment: Is the issue is the handgrips become loose on the bars or your hands become slippery on the grips??

Comment: @Criggie I am keen to try this on my 2006 Brompton as I struggle to find suitable 100mm grips.  Any thoughts on how I should double wrap the tape?

Comment: @Superman.Lopez Do the inner layer first.  You can simply tape the start down. then wrap, and tape again at the end.  Noone will see it so neatness isn't critical.  Do try to keep it flat - either overlap neatly or just butt the turns to each over.  Keep the tension on and consistent.  Can re-use old/crusty/cheap wrap.  Top layer should be nice new wrap and overlap properly.  Second layer should wind from outside toward centerline.  If you don't like how it goes, unwrap and try again.